# Why do postfix operators in Java get evaluated from right to left?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

Suppose we have the following code snippet in Java:

```
int a = 3;
int b = a++;
```

The value of `a` gets assigned to `b` first and then it gets incremented. `b = 3` and `a = 4`. Then why does the postfix expression get evaluated from right to left? Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be evaluated from left to right?

Comment: How is the ternary operator evaluated from right to left? Surely for `a?b:c` the evaluation order is `a` then either `b` or `c`, depending on the value of `a`.

Comment: Evaluation order only applies if there are multiple things to evaluate. Your example doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of confusion here. Java **always** evaluates from left to right (or to be more precise, always pretends to do so), as stated in the JLS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.

What you're talking about is the direction of associativity, that is if an operand is sandwiched between two operations **of the same precedence**, which one is the operand bound to. So the ternary operator for example is right-associated because if you've got `a?b?c:d:e`, you expect it to resolve to `a?(b?c:d):e`

But the postfix `++`, on the same precedence level as the '.' operator is left-to-right associated, which is why `foo.bar++` works.

The prefix `++` is indeed right grouping because `++++x` should really be `++(++x). Since it's a unary operator and the operand is to the right, it must group to the right.

Answer (score 2):

The postfix operators are not evaluated right-to-left; their side-effect happen *after* the value is determined (roughly speaking - the JLS specifies the order).

Comment: I am reading OCA Java SE 7 Associate Study Guide. Chapter 3 of the book clearly says that the postfix increment and decement operators are evaluated from right to left. I also verified the same from http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/CSE8A/Java_Operator_Precedence_Table.pdf

Comment: That's associativity, not evaluation order.

Comment: Thanks! That helped clarify everything... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important
gives an excellent explanation of operator associativity.

Comment: @Prachi You're welcome, I've tried to give a not-so-excellent one here too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually: No. This is the expected behaviour. Compare `a++` with `++a`. If you would do the last one, you would get a=4, b=4.

Comment: Well it does make sense for the prefix operators to get evaluated from right to left. Update a first and then b. But in the postfix operators, b is getting updated before a. So it makes more sense to have it read from left to right... at least to me.