# What does the `<<` operator mean in elm?

Tags: elm

In the following code taken from [Elm Form Example](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Intermediate/Form.elm), line 122, what does the `<<` operator mean?

```
Field.field Field.defaultStyle (Signal.send updateChan << toUpdate) "" content
```

Couldn't find it in [Elm syntax reference](http://elm-lang.org/learn/Syntax.elm).

Does it mean, when the field changes, instead of sending its `content` to `updateChan`, send `toUpdate` to `updateChan`?

Comment: If you are coming from Haskell: `<<` is the analog of `.` in Haskell

Answer (score 138):

[`<<`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#%3C%3C) is a function composition operator, defined in core library [`Basics`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics). All functions from Basics are imported into Elm projects unqualified.

#### Elm's type system

Let's recall basics of Elm type system.

Elm is [statically typed](http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem#contracts). This means that in Elm every variable or function has a type, and this type never changes. Examples of types in Elm are:

- `Int`
- `String`
- `Maybe Bool`
- `{ name : String, age : Int }`
- `Int -> Int`
- `Int -> String -> Maybe Char`.

Static typing means that compiler ensures types of all functions and variables are correct during compilation, so you don't have runtime type errors. In other words, you'll never have a function of type `String -> String` receiving or returning `Int`, code that allows this won't even compile.

You can also make your functions polymorphic by replacing a concrete type such as `String` or `Maybe Int` with a type variable, which is an arbitrary lowercase string, such as `a`. Many Elm core functions are type polymorphic, for example [`List.isEmpty`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/List#isEmpty) has the type `List a -> Bool`. It takes a `List` of some type and returns a value of type `Bool`.

If you see the same type variable again, then instances of this type variable must be of same type. For example [`List.reverse`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/List#reverse) has type `List a -> List a`. So if you apply `List.reverse` to a list of integers (i.e. to something that has type `List Int`), it *will* return a list of integers back. No way such function can take a list of integers, but return a list of strings. This is guaranteed by the compiler.

All functions in Elm are [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321/596361) by default. This means that if you have a function of 2 arguments, it is transformed into a function of 1 argument that returns a function of 1 argument. That's why you function application syntax of Elm is so different from function application in other languages such as Java, C++, C#, Python, etc. There's no reason to write `someFunction(arg1, arg2)`, when you can write `someFunction arg1 arg2`. Why? Because in reality `someFunction arg1 arg2` is actually `((someFunction arg1) arg2)`.

Currying makes [partial application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218025/596361) possible. Suppose you want to partially apply [`List.member`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/List#member). `List.member` has a type `a -> List a -> Bool`. We can read the type as “`List.member` takes 2 arguments, of type `a` and type `List a`”. But we can also read the type as “`List.member` takes 1 argument of type `a`. It returns a function of type `List a -> Bool`”. Therefore we can create a function `isOneMemberOf = List.member 1`, which will have the type `List Int -> Bool`.

This means that `->` in type annotations of functions is right-associative. In other words, `a -> List a -> Bool` is the same as `a -> (List a -> Bool)`.

#### Infix and prefix notation

Any [infix operator](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#infix-operators) is actually an ordinary function behind the curtains. It's just when a function name consists solely of non-alphanumeric symbols (such as $, <|, <<, etc), it is placed between 2 arguments, not in front of them (like ordinary functions).

But you still can put a binary operator like `+` in front of the 2 arguments, by enclosing it in parentheses, so the 2 function applications below are equivalent:

```
2 + 3 -- returns 5
(+) 2 3 -- returns 5, just like the previous one
```

*Infix operators are just ordinary functions.* There's nothing special about them. You can partially apply them just like any other function:

```
addTwo : Int -> Int
addTwo = (+) 2

addTwo 3 -- returns 5
```

#### Function composition

[`(<<)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#%3C%3C) is a function composition operator, defined in core library [`Basics`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics). All functions from basics are imported into Elm projects unqualified, meaning you don't have to write `import Basics exposing (..)`, it is already done by default.

So just like any other operator, `(<<)` is just a function, like any other. What is its type?

```
(<<) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Because `->` is right-associative, this is equivalent to:

```
(<<) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

In other words, `(<<)` takes 2 functions of types `b -> c` and `a -> b` respectively, and returns a function of type `a -> c`. It composes 2 functions into one. How does that work? Let's look at a contrived example for simplicity's sake. Suppose we have 2 simple functions:

```
addOne = (+) 1
multTwo = (*) 2
```

Suppose we don't have `(+)`, only `addOne`, how would we create a function that adds 3, not 1? Very simple, we would compose `addOne` together 3 times:

```
addThree : Int -> Int
addThree = addOne << addOne << addOne
```

What if we want to create a function that adds 2, then multiples by 4?

```
ourFunction : Int -> Int
ourFunction = multTwo << multTwo << addOne << addOne
```

`(<<)` composes functions from right-to-left. But the above example is simple, because all the types are the same. How would we find a sum of all even cubes of the list?

```
isEven : Int -> Bool
isEven n = n % 2 == 0

cube : Int -> Int
cube n = n * n * n

ourFunction2 : List Int -> Int
ourFunction2 = List.sum << filter isEven << map cube
```

`(>>)` is the same function, but with arguments flipped, so we can write the same composition from left to right instead:

```
ourFunction2 = map cube >> filter isEven >> List.sum
```

#### Recap

When you see something like `h << g << f`, then you know that `f`, `g`, `h` are functions. When this construct `h << g << f` is applied to a value `x`, then you know:

- Elm first applies `f` to `x`
- then applies `g` to the result of the previous step
- then applies `h` to the result of the previous step

Therefore `(negate << (*) 10 << sqrt) 25` equals `-50.0`, because you first take a square root of 25 and get 5, then you multiply 5 by 10 and get 50, then you negate 50 and get -50.

#### Why << and not .

Before Elm 0.13 (see [announcement](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.13)) function composition operator was `(.)`, and its behavior was identical to current `(<<)`. `(<<)` was adopted in Elm 0.13 from F# language (see [Github issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-lang.org/issues/158)). Elm 0.13 also added `(>>)` as equivalent to `flip (<<)`, and [`(<|)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#%3C|) as replacement for function application operator `($)`, and [`(|>)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#|%3E) as equivalent to `flip (<|)`.

#### Infix function call

You might be wondering if you can turn an ordinary alphanumeric function name into an infix binary operator. Before Elm 0.18 you'd use backticks to make a function infix, so below 2 would be equivalent:

```
max 1 2 -- returns 2
1 `max` 2 -- returns 2
```

Elm 0.18 [removed this feature](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md#backticks-and-andthen). You can't do it in Elm anymore, but languages like [Haskell](http://haskell.org) and [PureScript](http://purescript.org) still have it.

Comment: I wish this guy was my teacher. This needs to be in the official documentation which I should add lacks some critical information for beginners in functional ML based languages.

Answer (score 25):

[`<<`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#<<) is a function composition - returns function.

Composition creates a pipe of computations, chain of functions. This pipe waits for input, and when provided, first function starts computation, sends output to next etc.

```elm
import Html

add x y =
    Debug.log "x" x + Debug.log "y" y

add9 =
    add 4 << add 5

main =
    Html.text <| toString <| add9 2
```

**Note**: *In the above example I use [partial application](http://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/01-foundations/02-functions.html). It means that I don't provide all parameters to function and as a result I get function.*

If you run above example in web browser and look at the console output, you will see:

```elm
x: 5
y: 2
x: 4
y: 7
```

If we write it as math operations it will look like this:

```elm
4 + (5 + 2)
4 + 7
```

**Note**: *We can also use forward version `>>`.*

## Reading signatures

Looking at signature of this operator:

```elm
(<<) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

For `<<` operator, there is a function `b -> c` as the first parameter, and a function `a -> b` as the second:

`(b -> c) << (a -> b)`

But there is also a third parameter `a`. Because `->` is right-associative, then

`(<<) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

is equivalent to:

`(<<) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`.

So that `<<` returns function `a -> c`.

## Associativity

In programming languages, the associativity (or fixity) of an operator is a property that determines how operators of the same precedence are grouped in the absence of parentheses; i.e. in what order each operator is evaluated:

`a = b = c` is parsed as `a = (b = c)`

- [What is associativity of operators and why is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important/930498#930498)
- https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-explain-the-right-to-left-associativity-of-the-conditional-operator-in-C

## Infix operator

Here I use `<<` as [infix operator](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#infix-operators), but we can also use it as a prefix operator enclosing it with parenthesis: `(<<) (b -> c) (a -> b)` or `(<|) (add 4) (add 5)`.

elm < 0.18 [used to](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md#backticks-and-andthen) let you take normal functions and use them as infix operators.

## A word about `<|` operator

[`<|`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#<|) is a function application - returns value

We basically use it instead of parentheses.

`text (something ++ something)`

can be written as

`text <| something ++ something`

So looking at [signature](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#infix-operators) of this operator:

```elm
(<|) : (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

we can see that for `<|` operator, there is a function `a -> b`  as the first parameter, and value `a` as the second:

`(a -> b) <| a`

and it returns `b`.

We can get the same value with function application `<|`:

```elm
v1 = add 4 <| add 5 <| 4
v2 = (add 4 << add 5) 4
```

- There is also forward version of this operator `|>`.
- https://elm-community.github.io/elm-faq/#what-good-is-the--operator-if-it-is-just-function-application
- For clarity [don't mix](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/49s8o2/help_with_basics_of_function_composition/) `<|` and `<<`

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but is "lazy chain of functions" applicable in this context? Isn't Elm strictly evaluated? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/9XxV9L0zoA0

Answer (score 11):

It is function composition. For your concrete example it means

```
\x -> (Signal.send updateChan (toUpdate x))
```

In elm it's not a part of the syntax but part of the standard library: [Basics.<<](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Basics#%3C%3C)

Comment: But `<<` takes two functions, if `f` and `g` both are functions, I can see that `f << g` means `\x -> f (g x)`. In my example, with whom does `toUpdate` composite, some hidden identity function? Since `updateChan` is not a function, if you write `updateChan << toUpdate`, wouldn't this cause error?

Comment: I couldn't find this snippet it the sources you provided. From `send` and Field signatures I assumed that some Data type is used there, so `updateChan` is a `Channel Data` and `toUpdate` is a function of form `String -> Data`. That gives  `(Signal.send updateChan)` has type `Data -> Message` and `(Signal.send updateChan) << toUpdate` has type `String -> Message`.

Answer (score 4):

My second attempt :D

### `<<` vs `<|`

The difference between `<<` and `<|` is that `<<` is used to compose functions and `<|` is used to omit parentheses.

### Why it works like that

Let's look at type annotation found [here](http://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/?q=%3C%3C):

```elm
<< : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

This definition tells us, that when you pass two functions to function `<<`, you will get function `a -> c`.

### Example with [demo](https://ellie-app.com/V4jJrXf3xZa1)

```elm
hi a =
    a + 2
hello a =
    a * 2
bye =
    hello << hi
c =
    bye 3
```

`c` returns value `10`.

### Read more about:

- [infix operators](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#infix-operators) - first argument on the left of function,
- [partial application](https://dev.to/matt24ray/partial-application-of-functions-in-elm-ll) - when you pass one argument to function expecting two arguments, you get function expecting one argument.

Answer (score 4):

Explantion for `javascript` developers:

```
--elm

(a << b) x
```

Will be similar

```
//javasript

a(b(x))
```

`<<` or `>>` is called [function composition](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#%3C%3C)

Answer (score 0):

In this response, I show the difference between `<|` and `<<`.

```
> addOne a = a + 1
<function> : number -> number
```

Code example with `<|`:

```
> addThree a = addOne <| addOne <| addOne a
<function> : number -> number
> addThree 4
7 : number
```

`addThree` alternative version based on function composition `<<`:

```
> addThreeComposition = addOne << addOne << addOne
<function> : number -> number
> addThreeComposition 4
7 : number
```