# Calling a JSON Value by giving the key as variable?

Tags: javascript, json, oop

I want to call a JSON value by giving the key via a variable.

Given 
`if (data[airplane].RunwayThreshold !== undefined){}`

Can I make RunwayThreshold a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain bracket access:

```
data[airplane][RunwayThreshold]
```

although you may want to check for undefined values along the chain.

Because access is [left-associative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930505/129032), that becomes:

```
(data[airplane])[RunwayThreshold]
```

and allows you to drill down into objects.