# Undefined behavior in c/c++: i++ + ++i vs ++i + i++

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, side-effects, sequence-points

Imagine that we have the code below:

```
int i = 1;
int j = i++ + ++i;
```

I know that this is a Undefined Behavior, because before the semicolon, which is a sequence point, the value of `i` has been changed more than once. It means that the compiler may have two possibilities even if the precedence of operator plus is Left-to-Right:

case 1)

1. take the value of `i++` --- value of `i` is 1
2. take the value of `++i` --- value of `i` is 2
3. do the operator plus and assign the result which is 3 to `j` and do the side effect of `i++` (the order of this step is undefined too but we don't care because it won't change the result)

case 2)

1. take the value of `i++` --- value of `i` is 1
2. do the side effect of `i++` --- value of `i` is 2
3. take the value of `++i` --- current value of `i` is 3
4. do the operator plus and assign the result which is 4 to `j`

If nothing is wrong here, I have a question:

`int j = ++i + i++;`

Is the code above still an Undefined Behavior?

In my opinion, there is only one possibility:

1. do the side effect of `++i` --- value of `i` is 2
2. take the value of `i++` --- value of `i` is 2
3. do the operator plus and assign the result which is 4 to `j` and do the side effect of `i++` (the order of this step is undefined too but we don't care because it won't change the result)

Am I right?

Btw I've read this link:
[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735)

Comment: There are multiple ways to evaluate your second example just as there are multiple ways to evaluate your first example

Comment: You've missed the Undefined Behavior concept. Anything can happen. Program can crash. Program can output 42... etc. etc.

Comment: Both are UB. And "precedence of operator" is just how to parse and put parenthesis to the expression.

Comment: Case in point: [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4a135a3194a7d37) prints 4 for clang, but if you replace `clang++` with `g++` in the command line [you get 5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2481655ee923d7fe). Also, both warn about UB.

Comment: what makes you think the arguments need to be evaluated left to right?

Comment: You're confusing both associativity and precedence with evaluation order. The parameters are evaluated in an unspecified order. Associativity only matters if there is more than one binary operator.

Comment: BTW one compiler (I forgot which one) consistently evaluates operands of binary `+` right-to-left

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: The answer you linked to says: "i = ++i + i++;  // Undefined Behaviour".

Comment: @PeterT http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @molbdnilo Could you please use an example to explain the associativity? I don't understand.

Comment: @Thomas did I ask for precedence? I asked for [Order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Comment: @meagar The linked duplicate is about C. While there is a similar topic in C as well (which is somehow interited in C++), the evolving standards of C and C++ may vary how to handle this. (I didn't check.) However, I'm not so sure that a C question is the appropriate duplicate for this C++ question. Btw. the title might need to be adjusted as well. (I stumbled into this looking for a dupl. candidate for yet another (c++) question about this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int j = ++i + i++;
```

is still undefined behavior since `++i` and `i++` can be processed simultaneously in multiple pipelines in some CPUs, which will lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: But C++ standard  the precedence of operator plus is Left-to-Right. So how could `++i` and `i++` be processed simultaneously?

Comment: @Thomas. There is nothing like left-to-right precedence. There is left-to-right associativity.

Comment: What is "left-to-right" associativity?

Comment: @Thomas. Re. left-to-right associativity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important.

Comment: @Thomas Operator precedence defines in which order operations on values will be done but it is undefined when an expression (such as `++i`) will be turned into a value (evaluated). This is what makes it UB.

Comment: @StenSoft   OK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not correct.    Each of the expressions `++i` and `i++` modify `i`, so the statement modifies `i` more than once.   That is undefined behaviour.

Note that more recent versions of the standards no longer include the concept of "sequence point".

Comment: More recent versions of the standard no longer use the **term** "sequence point", but the concept is still there.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The notion of a sequence point would imply a global ordering of events--everything that happens before a sequence point precedes everything that happens after.  In many cases, however, the fact that A follows B and B follows C may not necessarily imply that A follows C.  For example, given `x = y & 1; z = x & 2;` a compiler would be required to compute `z` in the second statement based upon the value that will be assigned in the first statement, but if none of the variables are `volatile` it could move the write to `z` ahead of the read of `y`.

Comment: @supercat - your point being? That has always been allowed under the "as if" rule. For single-threaded programs, the change in wording was intended to make no changes from the requirements under the old wording.

Comment: @PeteBecker - more recent standards certainly have the concept of sequencing (e.g. some operation may be sequenced before another, some other set of operations are unsequenced in a statement).   Whether that means the concept of "sequence point" is maintained is debatable - I interpret it isn't since the term isn't there, you interpret that it is.  As you say, new requirements are worded to avoid inconsistencies with older requirements.

Answer (score -5):

```
int i = 1;
int j = i++ + ++i;
```

Evaluation will happen from Right to left, i.e. firstly `++i` will be processed then `i++`. So `j` will have value 4.

You will get a warning that "operation on 'i' may be undefined" but there is no problem with this expression.

Comment: There is no problem in relying on undefined behaviour?

Comment: If, as you say, "C++ is not a platform independent language", then your answer is not about C++, but about C++ with compiler X on operating system Y and hardware Z. Since X, y, and Z are not specified in your answer, it seems incorrect to me.

Comment: C++ is not platform independent language. I've seen in many codes where people have used a-lot of syntax which is undefined e.g.  `int arr[4] = {11, 12, 45, 34};
int *p = arr + 1;  `          In this case complier says the behaviour is undefined. But if we will deep dive in theory of C++ then it will clearly answers that which value will be returned.

Comment: Let's be practical, can you give me any example where two run for the following code will produce different outputs for the code  ` int i=1; std::cout<<++i + i++; ` . Consider any X, y, z

Comment: Yes, I can give an example. With clang++ `3.6.0-2ubuntu1~trusty1` and g++ `Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3` on Ubuntu 14.04 on `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz`, the clang++-compiled program prints 4 and the g++-compiled program prints 5.