# Absurd output. Gives different output with and w/o debugging. Need expert intervention

Tags: c++

So here's the question. **Find the output for the following code.**
perform in c++

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 int i=2;
 cout<<i++<<i<<i++<<i;
 cout<<i;
 }
```

This concept is based on post/pre increment operator. Based on this concept I predicted the output as 23344. Like I expected it was correct when I tried debugging this code. But without debugging i am getting the output as 34244. 
Is this even possible? BTW I tried this on Dev-C++ 5.11. Thanks :)

Comment: See [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) please.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: Hold on guys. I just need to know if the answer  23344 is correct or 34244 is correct. That's all.

Comment: @user0042 I'm concerned that we're linking to a duplicate that is only tagged for c, not c++.

Comment: @user0042 done!

Comment: It doesn't matter; it's undefined behaviour in both languages.

Comment: @I_love_coding There's no _correct_ answer for this. And that's certainly not c code.

Comment: This is guaranteed to output `23344` in C++17. Specifically, it's covered by point 19 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Just thought I should mention it what with all the "unconditionally undefined behaviour" talk.

Comment: @chris [Interesting to see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) how C++17 handles this.

Comment: Both answers are correct. 42 would also be correct. The behavior is undefined, which means that the language definition does not tell you what the effect of that code is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38501587/1460794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your construction invokes Undefined Behavior.

See [Undefined behavior in c/c++: i++ + ++i vs ++i + i++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900469/undefined-behavior-in-c-c-i-i-vs-i-i) and [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

```
 #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 int i=2;

 //cout<<i++<<i<<i++<<i; // UB! 

  cout<<i++; 
  cout<<i;
  cout<<i++;
  cout<<i;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to add that code,but felt it was irrelevant. I tried that too but again it gave different output when i tried it with and w/o debugging. As of now like other experts have mentioned i  believe it is due to undefined behaviour. But again thanks for the help.