# Why this code not giving desired output?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

int main() {

    float da,hra,s,gs;

    scanf("%f",&s);

    da=40/100*s; hra=20/100*s;

    gs=s+da+hra;

    printf("%f",gs);

    return 0; 
}
```

For example if i entered 25000 for s then output must be 40000 but it showing 25000.000000.

Comment: Considering this isn't valid C code from the very first line?

Comment: If you indent the code by 4 spaces, you can write `#include <stdio.h>` on the first line.  Or you need to explain what you mean by 'the editor'.  Note that you should write `#include <stdio.h>` — there really isn't an excuse to write `#include "stdio.h"`.

Comment: Next time, printf out those intermediate results like 'da', 'hra', (or use a 'real' debugger).  Had your done so, you would probably have avoided an SO question and got your ap working quicker:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the fix below.

Note the `40.0` and `20.0` instead of `40` and `20`. The issue is that you were doing integer division. `40 / 100 == 0`, so `da` was always `0`. Using `40.0 / 100` instead gives you floating point division and the value `0.4`, which is what you want to make your calculations correct. (The same holds for the computation of `hra`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float da, hra, s, gs;

    scanf("%f", &s);

    da = 40.0 / 100 * s;
    hra = 20.0 / 100 * s;
    gs = s + da + hra;

    printf("%f", gs);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c, when several operations occur in an expression, each part is evaluated and resolved in a predetermined order called *operator precedence*(priority) but multiplication and division have same precedence hence if two operators of same precedence  is present in an expression, *associativity* of operators indicate the order in which they execute. Here the associativity is from left to right.
(You can read more about it here [What is associativity of operators and why is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important)).

So when evaluated from left to right 40/100 undergoes integer division to give 0 and when multipled with s the result of *da* was also  0 and  and same with *hra*  giving the result 25000.
All you had to do was write

`da = s*40/100` and `hra = s*20/100`.

The the entire 
value would have been treated as float and your result would have been correct.
As implemented below,

```
#include<stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

int main() {

float da, hra, s, gs;

scanf("%f",&s);

da = s*40/100; 
hra = s*20/100;

gs=s+da+hra;
printf("s=%f, da=%f, hra=%f\n",s,da,hra);

printf("%f",gs);

return 0; 
}
```