# Associativity, Precedence and F# Pipe-forward

Tags: f#

The F# pipe-forward can be expressed as:

```
let (|>) x f = f x
```

For example:

```
let SimpleFunction (a : typeA) (b : typeB) (c : typeC)=
    printf "OK."

// No problem here.
SimpleFunction a b c

// Using pipe-forward
c |> SimpleFunction a b
// No problem here. Interpreted as the same as above.
```

However, according to the documentation, the pipe-forward operator is left-associative.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/

So, I expected the pipe-forward statement:

```
// Original Expression
c |> SimpleFunction a b

// to be equivalent to:
(c |> SimpleFunction) a b

// Which is equivalent to:
SimpleFunction c a b
// Error!! SimpleFunction takes typeA, then typeB, then typeC.
```

Why does the compiler not "interpret" the pipe-forward expression as the error expression? Do I have any confusion about the operator precedence/associativity?

---

Additional Sources:

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/09/fsharp-pipe-forward-and-pipe-backward/

[What is associativity of operators and why is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930486/what-is-associativity-of-operators-and-why-is-it-important)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Answer (score 10):

The associativitity of a binary operator only matters when you have two or more occurrences of *the same* operator. When you have different operators (here: `|>` and juxtaposition), what matters is their relative precedence.

Juxtaposition has a higher precedence than `|>`, therefore

```
c |> SimpleFunction a b
```

is parsed like

```
(c) |> (SimpleFunction a b)
```

so, by the definition of `|>`, it's equivalent to

```
(SimpleFunction a b) (c)
```

which would usually be written

```
SimpleFunction a b c
```

That last equivalence is due to juxtaposition being left-associative.

The fact that `|>` is left-associative means that an expression like

```
x |> f |> g
```

is parsed as

```
(x |> f) |> g
```

which is equivalent to

```
g (f x)
```

i.e. chains of `|>` express function composition — successive pipeline steps — and not passing more arguments to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are curried by default, you original expression is actually like this:

`c |> (SimpleFunction a b)` which then becomes `(SimpleFunction a b) c`. For this to work function application will have to have precedence.